# Are there people know how to copy the all of data in root to normal user below /home

Tags: backup, root

I use the root for a period of times,Now,I log on the normal user I created before,which environment is not as same as root. Are there people know how to copy the all of data in root to normal user below /home(entire cover)?

Comment: By `root` do you mean `/` or `/root`?

Comment: I always log on root which means user name.maybe is /root?? (My english is not well,sorry)

Answer (score 0):

If your new user is a sudoer, just use

```
sudo cp -R /root ~
```

then change the owner of the newly copied files to your new user (change 'username' to your actual user accordingly)

```
sudo chown -R username:username ~/root
```

Comment: @Super丨Tin if it answered your question then you should set the answer Accepted (green check mark), and if you like the answer you should upvote it.